# Structure with pointer and array of structures in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, nested

I'm trying to learn about nested structures and pointers in C. I made this as a test:

```
typedef struct xyz xyz_t;
struct xyz{
    int x, y, z;
};

xyz_t array[] = {
    {.x = 14, .y = 16, .z = 18}, 
    {.x = 34, .y = 36, .z = 38}, 
    {.x = 64, .y = 66, .z = 68},
};

typedef struct blue blue_t;
struct blue 
{
   int  *pointer;
};

int main() 
{
    blue_t red;
    red.pointer = &array;

    printf("%d",red.pointer[1].z);
}
```

The idea is to have the structure `red` have a pointer pointing to `array`, and then `print f.ex. array[1].z`.

What am I doing wrong? The compiler is telling me:

> assignment from incompatible pointer type
>
> [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] `red.pointer = &array;`
>
> request for member `x` in something not a structure or union
> `printf("%d",red.pointer[2].x);`

Comment: Why is `pointer` declared as pointing at an `int`?

Comment: You create a type-alias `xyz_t`, which from that point can be used like any other native type (e.g. `int`). So a pointer to `xyz_t` is simply `xyz_t *`.

Comment: Furthermore, the type of `&array` is not `xyz_t *`, it is `xyz_t (*)[3]` since it's a pointer to the *array* and not a pointer to the first element. A pointer to the first element would be `&array[0]`. Or (since arrays naturally *decays* to pointers to their first element) plain `array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The idea is to have the structure 'red' have a pointer pointing to 'array', and then print f.ex. array[1].z.

In that case, you need to have a pointer to `xyz_t` in your "blue" struct.

```
struct blue 
{
   xyz_t *pointer;
};
```

You need to drop the `&` from this `red.pointer = &array;`. `array` will be converted into a pointer to its first element in `red.pointer = array;` which is the correct type (to match LHS) See [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/1275169); whereas `&array` is of type `struct xyz (*)[3]`.

Aside, you could use a proper signature for main function (`int main(void)`). `red` could be a confusing a variable for a `blue_t` type!

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed. See if it helps:

```
typedef struct xyz{
    int x, y, z;
} xyz_t;

xyz_t array[] = {
    {.x = 14, .y = 16, .z = 18},
    {.x = 34, .y = 36, .z = 38},
    {.x = 64, .y = 66, .z = 68},
};

typedef struct {
    xyz_t *pointer;
} blue_t;

int main()
{
    blue_t red;
    red.pointer = &array;

    printf("%d",red.pointer[1].z);
}
```